# socketIOClient requesting to incorrect request URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Trying to connect to a websocket connection using socket.io but getting the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O8NSvG7
```

When I run a `GET` request on this url end point using postman I get this output:

```
Disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/testing/
11:37:50
{"type": "connection_established", "text": "connection successful"}
11:37:45
Connected to ws://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/testing/
```

I assume this means, I am successfully connecting, getting the message I have sent and then disconnecting, meaning this URL should return some output.

This is the code I am using in React to get data from my WebSocket URL endpoint:

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
...
const ENDPOINT = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/testing/';
...
        useEffect(() => {
            const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
            socket.on('FromAPI', data => {
                console.log('data is:', data)
            });
        }, []);
```